# chrome....onBeforeRequest...() URLs list not functioning as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am having some issues with an extension that i am trying to make. The extension's job is to check URLs before making the request and block the ones that are available in the list provided. *The manifest.json file loads flagged.js which declares and initializes the array. Then, it loads the file that has* the function to check URLs:

```
// To detected and filter globally flagged websites
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    // What to do if detected a website
    function(info) {

        return {redirectUrl: 'chrome-extension://' + chrome.i18n.getMessage('@@extension_id') + 
            '/blocked.html?flag_type=globally&url=' + escape(info.url)};
    },

    // Website to watchout for
    {
        urls: flagged,
        types: []
    },

    // Action to be performed?
    ["blocking"]);
```

My issue starts with the part ***urls: flagged,*** it seems the list must be hardwired in order to be accepted. What i mean to say, is that i must specify the list items as such:

```
var flagged = [
"*://*.domain_1.com/*",
"*://*.domain_2.com/*",
"*://*.domain_3.com/*",
"*://*.domain_4.com/*",
];
```

If i attempt to go to any of the above specified domains, the extension will redirect them to the ***block.html*** page no problems. However, i want that list to be automatically or periodically updated, so i introduced this part:

```
// Get list from the text file we have stored
function getFlagged(url) {
    var list = [];
    var file = new XMLHttpRequest();
    file.open("GET", url, true);
    file.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (file.readyState === 4) {
            if (file.status === 200) {
                allText = file.responseText; 
                list = file.responseText.split('|');
                    for( var i=0; i<list.length; i++ )
                        flagged.push(list[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    file.send(null);
}
```

I have tried to change and add things that may not make sense or could be done differently, i was just desperate. The list will be populated with the new items, say ***domain_5*** and ***domain_6*** for example. This operation will occur first thing when the extension is being loaded, or so i think. However, when i try to access ***domain_5*** and ***domain_6***, the extension does **NOT** block them despite the fact that they are in the list flagged.

Any help with this issue would be very appreciated!
Thank you

EDIT: I am not an expert on JS or Chrome.APIs, this is my first attempt at chrome extensions.

Comment: Maybe that's because you call `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener` before your `XMLHttpRequest` finishes?

Comment: Thank you for your response, i should have explained how i set the JSON file up. I have updated that in the main post. But, the array is initialized when i open the browser which is on extension load-up which is prior to the call of 'chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, Your Listener is registering before the XMLHttpRequest is finished.

Call the listener in your onreadystatechange function and you'll get it to work.